# Migrate UberSVN repository to another server

Tags: svn, ubuntu-12.04, ubersvn

I want to move repository from an old Ubersvn to a new one follow this [instruction](http://support.wandisco.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/372/46/moving-ubersvn-to-another-server). After that I can access my Ubersvn server from browser(mydomain:**9890**) but I can not checkout source code using tortoisesvn (mydomain:**9880**/myproject) and also can not access the link mydomain:**9880**/myproject from browser(show page not found)

Please help me!

I use Ubuntu Server 12.04, uberSVN Core 12.07.0693-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have backed up and restored your repositories they will not exist on the new server. The data contained in uberSVN's backup is specific to teams/users and rules.

FWIW there is a newer version of the helpfile in the uberSVN documentation [here](http://docs.ubersvn.com/v1.0/moving.html), rewritten when the backup tool was introduced.

Comment: Hi Mand Beckett, thanks so much for your answer, It works perfectly for me.